# Tuning hive queries

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hql

Is there any link which explains usage of hive configuration properties better that is used to run HQL better.

Got below link from my colleague , which is quite useful but not aware what each of the properties do in the background while running. Any input will be appreciated.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties

Comment: Hive is full of configs and each config has effect on execution. If you specifically ask some of the config you are looking for .. then..

Comment: Are you running Hive queries on MapReduce? Tez? Spark?

Comment: What file format(s) are you using: TextFile? SequenceFile? AVRO? Parquet? ORC? something else? *(for instance, ORC has a set of specific params)*

Comment: @samson I have tried Mapreduce/Tez . Tried Textfile and ORC wanted to understand role of each setting before I blindly use them

Comment: My 2 cents >> in most cases the default values are appropriate; it's when a specific query proves troublesome *(e.g. OutOfMemory on a join, a swarm of small output files, too many or too few Reducers considering the actual amount of data to reduce...)* or when you really need to gain a few % of processing time, that you have to dig into specific parameters to `set` for that specific query.

Comment: BTW you can search individual properties on StackOveflow e.g. `hive.merge.mapredfiles` will point to a number of posts (with overlap on `hive.merge.mapfiles` + `hive.merge.tezfiles` + `hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize`)

Comment: Thanks Samson  :)